# Folders/Files Iteration which ouput specific keywords including path and line numbers

Tags: ruby, bash, file

Here we go again!
I got lots of folders with contain many files in a directory. e.g.: index, controller, layout files etc.
My task is to iterate through each and every folders/files and try to find some specific keywords.

I got the answer using bash command.

```
grep '$this->' -R *.php -n > result.txt
```

It works but only pulling out one line at the time and just a broken syntax as I need to grab the whole code if the code is in multiple lines. The result will also can print out the paths/folders including which line details. I looked over the net and were suggested to use `Dir.glob`

> note: I prefer using ruby since It will be a lot more confused to me with other language. I am new to ruby and that the only language that I am learning as from now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
# Recursively get absolute paths of the files with specified extension in specified directory
#
# @param ext [String] extension of the files to look for (default - any extension)
# @param pwd [String] absolute or relative path where to look for the files (default - current directory)
# @param list [Array<String>] used to recursively store absolute paths (default - [])
# @return [Array<String>] Array array of absolute paths of files in the directory with specified extension
def files(ext = '.*', pwd = Dir.pwd, list = [])
  Dir[File.expand_path(File.join(pwd, '*'))].each do |path|
    if File.directory?(path)
      files(ext, path, list)
    else
      list << path if File.extname(path) =~ Regexp.new(ext, true)
    end
  end
  list
end

# Find all the files with provided extension in provided directory which contain keyword
#
# @param keyword [String] keyword to look for
# @param ext [String] extension of the files to look for (default - any extension)
# @param pwd [String] absolute or relative path where to look for the files (default - current directory)
# @param ignorecase [Bool] ignore case when searching for keyword if set to true (default - true)
# @return [Hash<String, Array<Integer>>] hash of the files which contain provided keyword.
# Key - file absolute path, value - array of number lines where the keyword is present
def find_keywords(keyword, ext = '.*', pwd = Dir.pwd, ignorecase = true)
  results = {}
  files(ext, pwd).each do |file|
    File.readlines(file).each_with_index do |line, line_number|
      if line =~ Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(keyword), ignorecase)
        results[file] ||= []
        results[file] << line_number + 1
      end
    end
  end
  results
end

p find_keywords('$thIs->', '.php')
#=> { "~/path/main.php" => [87, 99, 126], "~/path/config/sample.php" => [24], }
```

Comment: Thanks @Kirill basically the output that I need is a new file/s that output all of the string matching the keywords that I am looking for. The result will print out the block of code containing that's keyword including the line number and the path/folders where it's coming from..

Comment: @user5200113, what do you mean by "block of code"? Like the whole file? The code I've provided contains most of the functionality you need. How exactly you want output to look like is up to you.

Comment: what I mean by "block of code" simply not only showing the path and line numbers but also the code that containing those words in that file. thanks